# Web site not down but I cannot load it

Tags: internet, webpage

This has happened me 2nd times this week: I cannot load [Overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com/) while:

- Pages which check availability like http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/, http://currentlydown.com … (I tried like 4 of them ) says that the page is *not* down.
- Other pages (Google, Facebook, Stack Overflow, Wikipedia…) are working fine.
- I tried other browsers, restarting browsers, restarting the computer but the problem is still the same.
- I tried load the page on a colleague’s computer but it’s also not loading.

Could it be e.g.:

- Related to country (EU, Czech Republic)
- Related to the institution I am getting Internet connectivity from (possibly due to some mirror/proxy … I don’t think I use proxy - none is set in the web browser)

Comment: What is the error you receive when the page fails to load?

Comment: "This has happened me 2nd times this week" - This indicates its not a server problem, and not because of firewall filtering, but because of a DNS problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to your DNS.  Why don't you try using another server?  [Google's are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS):

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

If that works, you can change it permanently, though how you do that depends on which OS you're using.

Here's another, [OpenDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS).